# Is it possible to remove all App Configuration keys before deploying the new keys?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep, azure-app-configuration

I have a Bicep script that deploys an instance of App Configuration into a resource group.

We use the "incremental mode", as otherwise a deployment of a single instance would delete everything else on that resource group.

However, the problem is that if we delete key-values in the Bicep script (which reads the configs from a JSON file and loops through them to run `Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/keyValues`), the bicep deployment will add any **new** or **changed** key-values, but will **not** delete any removed key-values.

Is there a way to remove all key-values from the App Configuration before adding/updating the new values?

Comment: You mean using bicep ? you probab ly want to delete them before running the script using AzCli or AzPowershell ? Woul;d you be able to share your template please ?

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid using CLI or PowerShell, because that requires to know/hardcode the resource name, and I'd have to be restructuring the way the Pipeline templates already work. Basically, I have a YAML pipeline that runs YAML templates, which then run the CLI to deploy. However, the templates are supposed not to know what the bicep contains. They just "run it". And the YAML that invokes the template isn't supposed to know what the App Config resource name will be (it's up to the bicep modules). Hence I wanted to do it through bicep-only! Thanks!!

Comment: Terraform would work for you here but not sure if it is an option

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not when using incremental mode. The keyValues are their own freestanding resource so cannot be removed.

To stay "bicep-only" you'd need to leverage a DeploymentScript resource to do some cleanup for you. It's a clumsy workaround and I wouldn't recommend. I'd probably run a cleanup activity as part of my CI/CD pipeline.

I'd suggest you have a look at the [Deployment Stacks preview](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/2690) which (whilst Preview) introduces capabilities to help these kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You may create key-values with a new label every time, and then any old key-values won't be included when querying keys with the new label.

Alternatively, if feasible, the Azure App Configuration pipeline task supports [Delete key-values that are not included in the configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/push-kv-devops-pipeline#parameters).